# How to take var from inside of ng-repeat and pass it to the controller, than pass it back to ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a problem when im trying to pass the value Date from `ng-repeat` to the controller. I need controller to do some function for each element in `ng-repeat` but cant get this to work. Maybe someone could help me? I would appreciate it.
[Image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bydO0.png).
To be clear I want to take this date, and make a function which will return me day of the week from this date. I want to do this in similar way as i did with `$scope.todayDay`.

Here is some code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container fromTop" ng-init="workingTime.showWorkingTimeForWorker()">
    <h1 class="container">Hi {{currentUser.first_name}}, here are your working hours</h1>
    <h3 class="container">If you dont remember today is {{today}}, {{todayDay}}</h3>
    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="min-width: 80px;">Date</th>
            <th style="min-width: 80px;">Day</th>
            <th style="min-width: 80px;">From</th>
            <th style="min-width: 80px;">To</th>
            <th style="min-width: 80px;">Hours</th>
            <th style="min-width: 80px;">On position</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="workingTime in listOfWorkingTimesForWorker | orderBy: 'date'" ng-if="workingTime.date >= today">
            <td>{{ workingTime.date}}</td>
            <td>{{dayOfWeak}}</td>
            <td>{{ workingTime.from | date: "HH:mm"}}</td>
            <td>{{ workingTime.to | date: "HH:mm"}}</td>
            <td>{{ workingTime.to - workingTime.from}}h</td>
            <td><span ng-repeat="position in currentUser.positions">{{position.name}}</span></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
'use strict';

this.appControllers.controller('WorkingTimesController', [
    'WorkingTime', 'WorkerService', 'Position', '$scope', '$stateParams', 'ngNotify', '$state', function (WorkingTime, WorkerService, Position, $scope, $stateParams, ngNotify, $state) {

        this.showWorkingTimeForWorker = function() {
          var formatDate = function(date) {
              var d = new Date(date),
                  month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
                  day = '' + d.getDate(),
                  year = d.getFullYear();

              if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
              if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

              return [year, month, day].join('-');
          }
          $scope.listOfWorkingTimesForWorker = [];
          WorkerService.getWorkingTimesForWorker(function(res) {
            $scope.listOfWorkingTimesForWorker = res;
          });
          //$scope.today = formatDate(new Date());
          var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
          $scope.todayDay = days[new Date().getDay()];
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: can you make fiddle or plunker of sample code ?

Comment: ir can be problematic, cause its preety big app. THe thing is that i want to take `workingTime.date` out of `ng-repeat` and pass it to the controller so i can change it

Comment: after you set $scope.listOfWorkingTimesForWorker, loop it, find dayOfWeak of them and put it in a field in workingTime and use it in ng-repeat

Comment: Pay attention that you are mixing 'controller as' syntax with the old $scope binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you well, you want to manipulate the view and display only the day of the week inside your view.

To do so, a controller's function wouldn't be suitable. Instead, you should rather use a filter :

```
angular.module('yourAppName').filter('day', function() {
  return function(input) {
    var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
    return day[input.getDay()];
  };
});
```

Then, you simply need to use it as a filter in your view :

```
        <td>{{ workingTime.to | day}}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function within your controller that takes in a date as a parameter and returns the day of the week.

```
$scope.getDayOfWeek = function(date) {
    var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
    return days[date.getDay()];
}
```

And then call this method from the frontend in your table:

```
<td>{{ getDayOfWeek(workingTime.date) }}</td>
```

You can probably handle this without a method by putting the days array from above right on the scope, and then accessing it.

In controller:

```
$scope.days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
```

In view:

```
<td>{{ days[workingTime.date.getDay()] }}</td>
```

Comment: without a method its doing nothing and with method it give me error:
'date.getDay is not a function'

Comment: @DamianHong-MinhNguyen - my assumption was that workingTime.date was a [javascript date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). It doesn't seem like that is the case because of the error you got.

Comment: its an object from psql DB

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`date` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) instead:

```
<td>{{ workingTime.date | date:'EEEE'}}</td>
```

or you just create a proper function on the controller to transform the date to day-of-week:

```
$scope.dayOfWeek = function(date) {
    return days[date.getDay()];
}
```

and use in the HTML

```
<td>{{ dayOfWeek(workingTime.date)}}</td>
```

Comment: I forgot the ` | date:'EEEE'` (+1 for that ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

You can use the for return the name of day in week:

```js
var appControllers = angular.module("App", []);

appControllers.controller('WorkingTimesController', function($scope){
    $scope.showWorkingTimeForWorker = function() {
        var formatDate = function(date) {
            var d = new Date(date),
            month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
            day = '' + d.getDate(),
            year = d.getFullYear();
            
            if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
            if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
            
            return [year, month, day].join('-');
        };
        
        $scope.listOfWorkingTimesForWorker = [
            {from : new Date(2010, 11, 1), to : new Date(2011, 10, 1)},
            {from : new Date(2009, 03, 1), to : new Date(2010, 11, 1)},
            {from : new Date(2014, 09, 1), to : new Date(2015, 1, 1)}
        ];
    };
}).filter('dayNameOfWeek', function() {
    return function(input) {
        var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
        var dayofWeek = days[input.getDay()];
        return dayofWeek;
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="WorkingTimesController">
    <div class="container fromTop" ng-init="showWorkingTimeForWorker()">
        <h1 class="container">Hi {{currentUser.first_name}}, here are your working hours</h1>
        <h3 class="container">If you dont remember today is {{today}}, {{todayDay}}</h3>
        <table class="table table-striped table-condensed" border="1px">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>From</th>
                    <th>To</th>
                    <th>Day of week FROM</th>
                    <th>Day of week TO</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="workingTime in listOfWorkingTimesForWorker">
                    <td>{{workingTime.date}}</td>
                    <td>{{workingTime.from | date: "HH:mm"}}</td>
                    <td>{{workingTime.to | date: "HH:mm"}}</td>
                    <td>{{workingTime.from | dayNameOfWeek}}</td>
                    <td>{{workingTime.to | dayNameOfWeek}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```